# Rspec2 + Rails4: Testing for displayed model fields in form partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

**Question**

I'd like to write tests that check the model fields that are displayed in my "show" and "form" partials. I succeeded for "show", not for "form".

Main constrain: The solution must be able to loop through an Array that contains each names of the model fields.

I believe this case can be interesting for anyone that is trying to shorten his test script files, while having many fields, and having a complete control over what's displayed and what's not, so I'll put some efforts trying to find a solution, with your help if you please :)

**Form view**

Nothing fancy

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  = f.select :field_1, options_from_collection_for_select ...
  = f.text_field :field_2
  ...
```

**Actual situation**

I found an easy way for the "show" partial, here is how my spec file looks like:

```
def user_fields_in_show_view
  [:field_1, :field_2, ..., :field_n]
end

it 'display fields' do
  user_fields_in_show_view.each do |field|
    User.any_instance.should_receive(field).at_least(1).and_call_original
  end

  render
end
```

This works well.

-

But the exact same technique does not work in the "form" partial, using the same code

```
def user_fields_in_form_view # List of fields need to be different, because of the associations
  [:field_1_id, :field_2, ..., :field_n]
end

it 'display fields' do
  user_fields_in_form_view.each do |field|
    User.any_instance.should_receive(field).at_least(1).and_call_original
  end

  render
end
```

It whines like this:

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
Exactly one instance should have received the following message(s) but didn't: field1_id, field_2, ..., field_n
# Backtrace is long and shows only rspec/mock, rspec/core, rspec/rails/adapters, and spork files
```

**What I tried so far**

**1-** I commented out the stub part of my tests and output `rendered` to the console, to manually check what's generated by my view, and yes the fields are correctly generated.

**2-** I replaced `User.any_instance` by the model I assign to the view, error is slightly different but it still not working

```
it 'display fields' do
  user = create :user
  assign :user, user

  user_fields_in_form_view.each do |field|
    user.should_receive(field).at_least(1).and_call_original
  end

  render
end
```

Gives:

```
 Failure/Error: user.should_receive(field).at_least(1).and_call_original
   (#<User:0x0000000506e3e8>).field_1_id(any args)
       expected: at least 1 time with any arguments
       received: 0 times with any arguments
```

**3-** I change the code so the `it` is inside the loop, like this:

```
user_fields_in_form_view.each do |field|
  it 'display fields' do
    user = create :user
    assign :user, user

    user.should_receive(field).at_least(1).and_call_original

    render
  end
end
```

Same result as above

And I run out of options. I suspect the internals of FormBuilder to play a bad trick on me but I can't figure it out, I'm not very knowledgeable with those yet. Thanks for reading

Comment: What happens if you change `user.should_receive` to `User.any_instance.should_receive`? Does the test work in this case?

Comment: A more cryptic output message, but still not passing

Comment: Hmmm... this is interesting. Could you show the view code please? Also, are you sure you're calling `first_name`, `last_name` in the code? Maybe there is a code like `user.attributes.slice(*current_role.allowed_user_attrbutes).each { |k,v| ... }`?

Comment: I just edited my question, I will add what you ask in few minutes. Thanks for helping

Comment: I parsed a part of the view code during my last edit. Really there is nothing fancy, I have some helper methods but they only wrap my fields in divs and labels, prepare the option hash passed to the form builder etc... At the end of the chain it's Rails FormBuilder that do do all the work. No call to the model `attributes` nor anything like this. I have no gem nor custom class that extend FormBuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually try to write unit test as simple as possible. Loops in unit tests don't add much readability and are not very good practice in general. I'd rewrite the test like this:

```
it 'should display user name and email' do
  # note: `build` is used here instead of `create`
  assign :user, build(:user, first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe', email: 'jd@example.com')

  render

  rendered.should have_content 'John'
  rendered.should have_content 'Doe'
  rendered.should have_content 'jd@example.com'
end
```

Thus, we're not limiting the view in how it should render the first and the last name. For example, if our view uses the following (bad) code in order to render user's full name, then your test will fail, but my test will work just fine, because it tests the behaviour of the view, not its internals:

```
<%= user.attributes.values_at('first_name', 'middle_name').compact.join(' ') %>
```

Moreover, multiple assertions in one test is a bad smell too. Going one step further, I'd replace this test with three smaller ones:

```
it "should display user's first name" do
  assign :user, build(:user, first_name: 'John')
  render
  expect(rendered).to include 'John'
end

it "should display user's last name" do
  assign :user, build(:user, last_name: 'Doe')
  render
  expect(rendered).to include 'Doe'
end

it "should display user's email" do
  assign :user, build(:user, email: 'jd@example.com')
  render
  expect(rendered).to include 'jd@example.com'
end
```

========

**UPD**: Let's make it more dynamic in order to avoid tons of repetition. Tis doesn't answers why your spec fails, but hopefully represents working tests:

```
%i(first_name last_name email).each do |field|
  it "should display user's #{field}" do
    user = build(:user)
    assign :user, user
    render
    expect(rendered).to include user.public_send(field)
  end
end
```

In order to make these tests more reliable, make sure that user factory doesn't contain repetitive data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Which is a good approach. I edited my question with additional information explaining why I am trying to compact my code with loops. I'll be waiting to see if someone come-up with a more "automatic" solution than yours.

Comment: Ok seen. Yes I considered this already (you gave me this idea with  your original answer indeed), I'll keep it as a backup plan and will digging a bit more though, my hope it there is a solution that does not rely on value

Comment: Decided :) I'll go for your approach, you guys convinced me. Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure how you build your form, but if you use the `form_for`, `simple_form_for` or `formtastic_form_for` helpers, actually you are using a different object. You write something like (assume the basic `form_for`)

```
= form_for @user do |f|
```

and all methods are relayed to object `f`. Now `f.object` will point to `@user`, but is it a copy of `@user` or `@user` itself, I don't know. So I would expect that `User.any_instance` should work.

Regardless, when doing a view test, it is not important how the contents of a field are set, it is important that the contents of a field are set correctly. Suppose you build your forms yourself, you switch to another library to build your forms, and all your tests break, because it retrieves the data differently. And that should not matter.

So I am with @DNNX, and in your view tests you should test the content of the rendered HTML and not how the data is retrieved.

Comment: Alright, that's clear I'll follow your guys advise and rely on values in my test. Thanks for your time and advise :) Cheers